# What happens when the switch in this circuit is flipped?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

what would happen to lights A and B if the switch in this circuit is flipped?

[image: Circuit]

Comment: What do you mean by flipped?

Comment: Without bothering to check, I would say "nothing"

Comment: Are you assuming that the two voltages are identical, and the two lamps are identical? If so, you should state it. If not, you need to specify what their characteristics are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would focus on the current in the middle ($I_S$).

When the circuit is open $I_S=0$
$$I_A=I_B=\frac{V_A}{R_A+R_B}+\frac{V_B}{R_A+R_B}=\frac{V_A+V_B}{R_A+R_B}$$

When it is closed you have $I=(V/R)_A-(V/R)_B$ and this current either adds or subtracts from the current across the bulbs.

If $(V/R)_A$ is greater than $(V/R)_B$ then you will get
$$
\begin{align}
I_A&=\frac{V_A}{R_A+R_B}+\frac{V_B}{R_A+R_B}+\frac{V_A}{R_A}-\frac{V_B}{R_B}\\
I_B&=\frac{V_A}{R_A+R_B}+\frac{V_B}{R_A+R_B}-\frac{V_A}{R_A}+\frac{V_B}{R_B}
\end{align}
$$

In this case, A gets brighter and B gets dimmer.

If $(V/R)_A=(V/R)_B$ then nothing will change.

I don't know if this is correct. Haven't taken physics 2 in a while. But this would be my answer.